# pandas: counting numbers and combining results from apply

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am trying to count consecutive zeros (e.g. 2 consecutive zeros or 3 consecutive zeros) in groups and combine the results in a new dataframe.

```
raw_data = {'groups': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x','z','y', 'y', 'y','y', 'y', 'z'],
    'runs': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['groups', 'runs'])
```

Example in the dataframe above, first I want to know how many 2 consecutive zeros are in each group and then I want to know how many 3 consecutive zeros are in each group.

I want the results (preferably in a dataframe):

```
group    2_0s    3_0s
x         1       1
y         1       0
z         0       0
```

I am hoping to find a generic way, as I want to be able to do the same for consecutive 1s and 2s as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
#get original unique sorted values of groups
orig = np.sort(df.groups.unique())
#add new groups for distinguish 0 in one group
df['g'] = (df.runs != df.runs.shift()).cumsum()
#filter only 0 values
df = df[df.runs == 0]
print (df)
   groups  runs  g
0       x     0  1
1       x     0  1
2       x     0  1
5       x     0  3
6       x     0  3
11      y     0  6
12      y     0  6

#get size by groups and g
df = df.groupby(['groups', 'g']).size().reset_index(name='0')
print (df)
  groups  g  0
0      x  1  3
1      x  3  2
2      y  6  2
```

```
#get size by groups and 0, unstack
#reindex by original unique values, add suffix to column names    
df1 = df.groupby(['groups','0'])
        .size()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .reindex(orig, fill_value=0)
        .add_suffix('_0s')

print (df1)
0       2_0s  3_0s
groups            
x          1     1
y          1     0
z          0     0
```

More generic solution:

```
df['g'] = (df.runs != df.runs.shift()).cumsum()
df = df.groupby(['groups', 'g', 'runs']).size().reset_index(name='0')
df1 = df.groupby(['groups','runs', '0']).size().unstack(level=[1,2]).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df1)
runs    0     1     2
0       2  3  2  3  1
groups               
x       1  1  1  0  0
y       1  0  0  1  0
z       0  0  0  0  2
```

Comment: Thanks jerael. That solves the problem, however, I was wondering whether it would be better to use apply and define a function that returns a series of counts of consecutive 2_0s, another function for 3_0s etc. One could just add that column to another dataframe with the same number of groups. Would that be efficient?

Comment: Also can you explain how to access columns from the final result. For instance, how to access the second column, where we have 3 consecutive 0s.